# Two side-by-side long lists

Tags: lists, text, sidebyside

I want to create two itemized lists and put them side by side. The lists are very very long, and i tried every solutions find on internet, but i can't make it works.
The text listed is something like:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus facilisis orci non auctor aliquet. In eu venenatis neque. Maecenas dapibus mi ac libero pharetra egestas. Maecenas scelerisque suscipit lectus. Nunc dictum eget lorem eget facilisis. Sed turpis tortor, rutrum sit amet est dictum, suscipit mollis purus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis dapibus, neque et dapibus venenatis, nulla nibh volutpat orci, eu tristique orci tellus non neque. Morbi commodo mollis elit nec volutpat. Vestibulum pharetra, massa vitae convallis pellentesque, eros est fermentum arcu, quis lobortis tortor nisl sit amet libero. Curabitur tempor libero et pulvinar varius. Aliquam nibh orci, efficitur sed porttitor nec, tempus ut risus. Aenean dapibus mattis odio ac vulputate. Maecenas in consectetur magna. Vestibulum facilisis porttitor dolor, nec imperdiet eros pretium non.

Fusce in porta ligula. Ut lacinia turpis neque, ac sagittis eros aliquam ut. Donec lacinia eros quis diam tempor sollicitudin. Etiam neque nulla, sodales sed vestibulum non, rutrum et ligula. Praesent nec pulvinar nisi, ac bibendum enim. Donec et iaculis eros. Aliquam congue libero purus. Sed posuere, quam eget consectetur sodales, nisl magna accumsan leo, in lacinia enim ante eget lacus. Nullam ex metus, luctus eget neque eu, tristique consectetur dolor. Ut ullamcorper turpis velit, eget maximus arcu faucibus fermentum. Phasellus lacus augue, semper in elit eu, egestas cursus tellus. Suspendisse turpis odio, pretium vitae euismod id, dictum in arcu. Vestibulum condimentum sapien lectus, in iaculis tellus malesuada id. Cras euismod nulla a eros elementum semper. Proin a ex nibh.

Aliquam finibus efficitur purus ut cursus. Sed convallis risus et purus dictum sagittis. Cras rhoncus, leo ac euismod varius, urna turpis rhoncus lacus, id hendrerit nisl nunc sed libero. Suspendisse eleifend ultricies aliquet. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce id leo sollicitudin, aliquet velit non, dapibus ante. Ut nec venenatis lorem.

Sed vitae pulvinar metus. Vivamus accumsan augue id turpis varius, eget feugiat dolor ultricies. Duis condimentum sit amet turpis vitae viverra. Proin eu dui vitae nulla gravida fringilla. Vivamus quis convallis justo. Vivamus aliquam lorem ut metus pulvinar ultrices. Etiam non ante nulla. Aenean convallis est vitae rutrum pulvinar. Suspendisse volutpat tortor mauris, sed tristique metus lobortis at. Fusce pulvinar, sapien vel viverra semper, tellus ante sodales neque, sit amet pretium quam sapien eget arcu. Nullam rutrum sem leo, sit amet hendrerit magna bibendum laoreet. Maecenas vitae quam eu neque gravida sodales.Cras sapien enim, pharetra non finibus a, laoreet non leo. Curabitur quam justo, ultrices et ante a, efficitur commodo risus. Donec pulvinar porttitor lorem. Sed nec semper nisi. Vestibulum sed iaculis diam. Nunc in accumsan elit. Suspendisse suscipit elit et eleifend pellentesque.

multiplied 2/3 times each list. so i need that it goes on multiple pages. I tried longtable but it doesn't work. It goes out of margin.

I used this:

```
    \begin{longtable}{lp{0.48\textwidth}}
    \caption{Example}
   \label{tab:longtable} \\
\toprule
Title Column 1 & Title Column 2 \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize\itshape
Continue} \\
\toprule
`Title Column 1 & Title Column 2 \\`
`\midrule`
`\endhead`
`\midrule`
`\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape`
Continue} \\`
`\endfoot`
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape
Finished} \\
\endlastfoot

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus facilisis orci non auctor aliquet. In eu venenatis neque. Maecenas dapibus mi ac libero pharetra egestas. Maecenas scelerisque suscipit lectus. Nunc dictum eget lorem eget facilisis. Sed turpis tortor, rutrum sit amet est dictum, suscipit mollis purus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis dapibus, neque et dapibus venenatis, nulla nibh volutpat orci, eu tristique orci tellus non neque. Morbi commodo mollis elit nec volutpat. Vestibulum pharetra, massa vitae convallis pellentesque, eros est fermentum arcu, quis lobortis tortor nisl sit amet libero. Curabitur tempor libero et pulvinar varius. Aliquam nibh orci, efficitur sed porttitor nec, tempus ut risus. Aenean dapibus mattis odio ac vulputate. Maecenas in consectetur magna. Vestibulum facilisis porttitor dolor, nec imperdiet eros pretium non.

Fusce in porta ligula. Ut lacinia turpis neque, ac sagittis eros aliquam ut. Donec lacinia eros quis diam tempor sollicitudin. Etiam neque nulla, sodales sed vestibulum non, rutrum et ligula. Praesent nec pulvinar nisi, ac bibendum enim. Donec et iaculis eros. Aliquam congue libero purus. Sed posuere, quam eget consectetur sodales, nisl magna accumsan leo, in lacinia enim ante eget lacus. Nullam ex metus, luctus eget neque eu, tristique consectetur dolor. Ut ullamcorper turpis velit, eget maximus arcu faucibus fermentum. Phasellus lacus augue, semper in elit eu, egestas cursus tellus. Suspendisse turpis odio, pretium vitae euismod id, dictum in arcu. Vestibulum condimentum sapien lectus, in iaculis tellus malesuada id. Cras euismod nulla a eros elementum semper. Proin a ex nibh.

Aliquam finibus efficitur purus ut cursus. Sed convallis risus et purus dictum sagittis. Cras rhoncus, leo ac euismod varius, urna turpis rhoncus lacus, id hendrerit nisl nunc sed libero. Suspendisse eleifend ultricies aliquet. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce id leo sollicitudin, aliquet velit non, dapibus ante. Ut nec venenatis lorem.

Sed vitae pulvinar metus. Vivamus accumsan augue id turpis varius, eget feugiat dolor ultricies. Duis condimentum sit amet turpis vitae viverra. Proin eu dui vitae nulla gravida fringilla. Vivamus quis convallis justo. Vivamus aliquam lorem ut metus pulvinar ultrices. Etiam non ante nulla. Aenean convallis est vitae rutrum pulvinar. Suspendisse volutpat tortor mauris, sed tristique metus lobortis at. Fusce pulvinar, sapien vel viverra semper, tellus ante sodales neque, sit amet pretium quam sapien eget arcu. Nullam rutrum sem leo, sit amet hendrerit magna bibendum laoreet. Maecenas vitae quam eu neque gravida sodales.Cras sapien enim, pharetra non finibus a, laoreet non leo. Curabitur quam justo, ultrices et ante a, efficitur commodo risus. Donec pulvinar porttitor lorem. Sed nec semper nisi. Vestibulum sed iaculis diam. Nunc in accumsan elit. Suspendisse suscipit elit et eleifend pellentesque. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus facilisis orci non auctor aliquet. In eu venenatis neque. Maecenas dapibus mi ac libero pharetra egestas. Maecenas scelerisque suscipit lectus. Nunc dictum eget lorem eget facilisis. Sed turpis tortor, rutrum sit amet est dictum, suscipit mollis purus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis dapibus, neque et dapibus venenatis, nulla nibh volutpat orci, eu tristique orci tellus non neque. Morbi commodo mollis elit nec volutpat. Vestibulum pharetra, massa vitae convallis pellentesque, eros est fermentum arcu, quis lobortis tortor nisl sit amet libero. Curabitur tempor libero et pulvinar varius. Aliquam nibh orci, efficitur sed porttitor nec, tempus ut risus. Aenean dapibus mattis odio ac vulputate. Maecenas in consectetur magna. Vestibulum facilisis porttitor dolor, nec imperdiet eros pretium non.

Fusce in porta ligula. Ut lacinia turpis neque, ac sagittis eros aliquam ut. Donec lacinia eros quis diam tempor sollicitudin. Etiam neque nulla, sodales sed vestibulum non, rutrum et ligula. Praesent nec pulvinar nisi, ac bibendum enim. Donec et iaculis eros. Aliquam congue libero purus. Sed posuere, quam eget consectetur sodales, nisl magna accumsan leo, in lacinia enim ante eget lacus. Nullam ex metus, luctus eget neque eu, tristique consectetur dolor. Ut ullamcorper turpis velit, eget maximus arcu faucibus fermentum. Phasellus lacus augue, semper in elit eu, egestas cursus tellus. Suspendisse turpis odio, pretium vitae euismod id, dictum in arcu. Vestibulum condimentum sapien lectus, in iaculis tellus malesuada id. Cras euismod nulla a eros elementum semper. Proin a ex nibh.

Aliquam finibus efficitur purus ut cursus. Sed convallis risus et purus dictum sagittis. Cras rhoncus, leo ac euismod varius, urna turpis rhoncus lacus, id hendrerit nisl nunc sed libero. Suspendisse eleifend ultricies aliquet. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce id leo sollicitudin, aliquet velit non, dapibus ante. Ut nec venenatis lorem.

Sed vitae pulvinar metus. Vivamus accumsan augue id turpis varius, eget feugiat dolor ultricies. Duis condimentum sit amet turpis vitae viverra. Proin eu dui vitae nulla gravida fringilla. Vivamus quis convallis justo. Vivamus aliquam lorem ut metus pulvinar ultrices. Etiam non ante nulla. Aenean convallis est vitae rutrum pulvinar. Suspendisse volutpat tortor mauris, sed tristique metus lobortis at. Fusce pulvinar, sapien vel viverra semper, tellus ante sodales neque, sit amet pretium quam sapien eget arcu. Nullam rutrum sem leo, sit amet hendrerit magna bibendum laoreet. Maecenas vitae quam eu neque gravida sodales.Cras sapien enim, pharetra non finibus a, laoreet non leo. Curabitur quam justo, ultrices et ante a, efficitur commodo risus. Donec pulvinar porttitor lorem. Sed nec semper nisi. Vestibulum sed iaculis diam. Nunc in accumsan elit. Suspendisse suscipit elit et eleifend pellentesque. \\

\end{longtable}
```

Any tips?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please share what you tried so far?

Comment: Try xltabular as it is the child to longtable and tabularx.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've tried xltabular but it's always overfull...and out of margin!

Comment: You have long text also in the first column, with has a single-lined specifier (`l`).

Comment: Related: [multicolumn long table or enumeration](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/13895)

Comment: Would you mind adding a sketch of the expected output to your question? In the body of your question you mention "two itemized lists" but the code you provided does not contain any itemize environment, but instead a `longtable`. Could you clarify that?

Comment: longtable would work but paracol or similar is probably more suitable but you put the long text in an `l` column so forcing it to be a single left-aligned line so not surprising it was too wide, you want two p columns.

Comment: Ok for the longtable, but can someone write an example? The output with parcol is near to what i need, but it's not perfect. it splits footnotes in 2 columns (i prefer footnote not splitted) and it doesn't allign correctly the citation. i've tried longtable again, but i can't figure how to make it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're interested in the following solution based on `paracol`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[5]

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}
\switchcolumn
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[5]
\item \lipsum[6]
\item \lipsum[7]
\item \lipsum[8]
\end{itemize}
\end{paracol}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The output with parcol is near to what i need, but it's not perfect. it splits footnotes in 2 columns (i prefer footnote not splitted) and it doesn't allign correctly the citation, and i don't know why but i cant itemize it well, and i recive, for every item, alert "overfull hbox". Do you know how to fix it? Longtable is good too, but i don't know why it goes out of bottom margin

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some like this?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
%for numerated items
\usepackage{linguex}\AtBeginDocument{\Exindent.5em\Exlabelsep.5em}
\def\myenum#1{\noindent\parbox[t]{.5\linewidth}{\ex. #1\par}} 
% for bulleted items 
\def\myitem#1{\noindent\parbox[t]{.5\linewidth}{\begin{itemize}\item #1\end{itemize}}} 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-5]\par
\myenum{\lipsum[4][1-5]\footnotemark}\footnotetext{\lipsum[14][1-3]}
\myenum{\lipsum[5][1-5]}
\myenum{\lipsum[6][1-5]}
\myenum{\lipsum[7][1-5]}
\myitem{\lipsum[8][1]}
\myitem{\lipsum[9][1-3]}
\myitem{\lipsum[10][1-2]}
\myitem{\lipsum[11][1]}
\end{document}
```

Or you can use `hlist`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{hlist} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-5]\par
\begin{hlist}2
\hitem \lipsum[2][1-5]\footnotemark
\hitem \lipsum[3][1-5]
\hitem \lipsum[4][1-5]
\hitem \lipsum[5][1-5]
\hitem \lipsum[6][1-5]
\hitem \lipsum[7][1-5]
\end{hlist}
\footnotetext{\lipsum[14][1-3]}
\end{document}
```

...or `multienum`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{multienum} 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-5]\par
\begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxx{\lipsum[2][1-5]\footnotemark}{\lipsum[3][1-5]}\footnotetext{\lipsum[14][1-3]}
\mitemxx{\lipsum[4][1-5]}{\lipsum[5][1-5]}
\mitemxx{\lipsum[6][1-5]}{\lipsum[7][1-5]}
\end{multienumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `linguex` is really the a good choice if all you want is a numbered list like this. It's really designed for linguistics examples and has a rather idiosyncratic syntax, so I wouldn't recommend it as a generic way to format a list.

Comment: Yes, the syntax of `linguex` is peculiar, but allows normal text paragraphs between the enumerated items and mainly, it is simple (enough to me to assume the risks of the extra-label use).